# VBA language reference for Office 2004

Tags: vba, macos, ms-office, documentation, office-2003

Office 2003 has such things as the [Office 2003 Editions: Word VBA Language Reference](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=179BEE82-E6E6-4B78-AFF9-9A541167541F).

Is there such documentation for Office 2004 or is it assumed that the Office 2003 documentation covers Office 2004 adequately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It covers Mac as well. Any differences are noted directly in the helpfile (but there ain't many). Note that Outlook VBA doesn't apply to Entourage.

Comment: Good.  It's funny that the downloads don't mention the 2004 edition, and consist of a .exe archive.